# Time series of account value in TD Ameritrade app?

Tags: td-ameritrade

I'm using the TD Ameritrade Think or Swim app on my phone.

[image]

My app has this same screen when I open the app which tells me the account value at the current time.  I'm looking for this same value but over time.  So it would look like a line graph of account value through a time series graph.

Does TD Ameritrade have this feature?

Comment: Have you asked them? It's usually called "performance" or something similar

Comment: If you want to know about features of a commercial product, always start by asking those selling it. If their instructions are unclear or they are unresponsive, then go to Q&A sites such as their community forums or Stack Exchange. People will be more willing to make an effort to help you if you can show that you've tried to resolve it yourself first, and more able to help you if you can show what you have tried that didn't work.